# How to post data with the logged user's email in a session using nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using MEAN stack with Angular 6. There I have a form to submit ' height value.' I want to submit it with the logged  user's email. I have a separate schema for user. Following is my height schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

// Schema for height panel
var heightSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
userName: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
         ref: 'user'
    },
    height: {
        type: Number
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('heightValue', heightSchema);
```

Following is my post route.

```
    //post height values
router.post("/save", function (req, res) {
    var mod = new height(req.body,{userName : req.body["user.email"]});
    height.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            userName: req.user.email,
            height: req.body.height,
        },
        req.body,
        { upsert: true, new: true },
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                console.log(res);
                res.send(mod);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

What I have tried,

I tried this.

```
userName: req.user.email,
```

But I am unable to get the logged user's user id. Response shows 'Unexpected end of inputs' error. How can I achieve my requirement.
After trying so many methods finally updated the routes and the schema. But still the problem is same. Can anyone identify where I have gone wrong?

--UPDATED--

Here I return token.

```
passport.use('login', new localStrategy({
     usernameField : 'email',
     passwordField : 'password'
   }, async (email, password, done) => {
     try {

       //Find the user associated with the email provided by the user
       const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

       if( !user || user.status === false){
         //If the user isn't found in the database, return a message
         return done(null, false, { message : 'User not found'});
       }
       //Validate password and make sure it matches with the corresponding hash stored in the database
       //If the passwords match, it returns a value of true.
       const validate = await user.isValidPassword(password);
       if( !validate ){
         return done(null, false, { message : 'Wrong Password'});
       }
       //Send the user information to the next middleware
       return done(null, user, { message : 'Logged in Successfully'});
     } catch (error) {
       return done(error);
     }
   }));


passport.use(new JWTstrategy({
      //secret we used to sign our JWT
      secretOrKey : 'top_secret',
      //we expect the user to send the token as a query paramater with the name 'secret_token'
      jwtFromRequest : ExtractJWT.fromUrlQueryParameter('secret_token')
    }, async (token, done) => {
      try {
        //Pass the user details to the next middleware
        return done(null, token.user);
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    }));


class Service
{

    constructor()
    {

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param {type} req
     * @param {type} res
     * @param {type} next
     * @returns {undefined}
     *  Authenticate functionality.
     */
    async authenticate(req,res,next)
    {               
        passport.authenticate('login', async (err, user, info) => {
        try {
          if(err || !user){
            const error = new Error('An Error occured');        
            return next(error);
            } 

            req.login(user, { session : false }, async (error) => {
            if( error ) return next(error);  
             const token = this.getJWT(user);

            return res.json({ token });
          });   
        } catch (error) {
          return next(error);
        }
        })(req, res, next);
    }    

    /**
     * 
     * @param {type} user
     * @returns {Service.getJWT.token}
     * Create JWT token.
     */
    getJWT(user)
    {
        //We don't want to store the sensitive information such as the
        //user password in the token so we pick only the email and first name 
        const body = { email : user.email , firstName : user.firstName};
        // Token will be expired in 24 hours.
        const token = jwt.sign({ user : body },'top_secret',
        {
            expiresIn : '24h'
        }); 
        return token;
    }
}

module.exports = Service;
```

Comment: Most of what you have posted in the question is not relevant to the problem you are facing. What you are actually asking is this: "I am not able to get the user details back from the token when using PassportJS". Relevant code would be your code for the passport strategy in Node and the invokation of the "/save" endpoint from Angular. I believe that you need to specifically instruct PassportJS to serialize the user data and store it in the session and then send the session cookie back with your requests, both of which would have to be done explicitly. Without more code it's hard to say.

Comment: Actually what I want is to post extruded height value with the current user's email. I followed "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256193/how-to-post-and-get-data-unique-to-each-logged-in-user-with-express-and-mongoose" answer in this post. But it did not work. Ignoring that I am using Passport js is there any method to do it.